# Sometimes I cannot connect to my RDP (like now)

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

I am cannot connect to my RDP.
I see a message "This computer  can't connect to the remote computer".

The server is working. All the services are working. But I just cannot connect by remote desktop.

Sometimes it is happened. And I need to reboot. But I don't want to reboot.

What should I do?

There are 2 opened sessions for Administartor Account in idle state.
How can I log to those open RDP sessions

I tried:

```
mstsc /v:myip /console

and

mstsc /v:myip /admin
```

And it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft thinking that the session are active, and 2008 r2 limited to 2 active session.

So, Just need to see the session:

```
qwinsta
```

And the disconnect the *active* sessions:

```
tsdiscon {{sessionName || SessionID}
```

Now the problem is that you (me), cannot access the remote computer to run the commands, so you need to search a way to run it.

I for example pushed  a nodejs project and run the commands using

```
 require('child_process').exec()
```